# Invoke Direct Print dialog using automation script in Maximo

Tags: printing, maximo

I would like to know whether there is a way to invoke the direct print dialog using automation script ? for example I have a button which is tied to an action launch point that would perform some validation and invoke direct print. My Maximo version is 7.6.1.2 and I think using webclientsetsession() I can probably invoke however I'm not sure on how to get that done.

Answer (score 0):

```
from psdi.webclient.system.session import WebClientSession
from psdi.mbo import SqlFormat, MboConstants

webclientSession = service.webclientsession()
# modify the following with the name of the report you wish to direct print
reportName = 'reportname.rptdesign'

sqlFmt = SqlFormat(mbo, 'APPNAME=:1 AND REPORTNAME=:2')
sqlFmt.setObject(1, 'REPORT', 'APPNAME', app)
sqlFmt.setObject(2, 'REPORT', 'REPORTNAME', reportName)

whereClause = sqlFmt.format()
reportSet = mbo.getMboSet('$REPORTSPI','REPORT', whereClause)

# Set the discardable flag on the set as we won't be modifying it
reportSet.setFlag(MboConstants.DISCARDABLE, True)
reportSet.reset()
reportMbo = reportSet.moveFirst()

reportnum = str(reportMbo.getInt('REPORTNUM'))
dialogId = 'reportd' + reportnum
webclientSession.loadDialog(dialogId)
reportSet.close()
```